# Can GCM support multi-language user and content?

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

we are making a news app. Now we have three language options for our users and we have news in three languages. If a user choose English in the settings. we don't want them to receive the Malay language notification. Can we realize this kind effect with GCM(Google Cloud Messaging)?

Answer (score 0):

Sure , You can use

> different PubSub Topic for diffrent labguage

, 
When your select language then subscribe to that language so user will receive GCM notification of only his/her language.

```
GcmPubSub pubSub = GcmPubSub.getInstance(this);
        pubSub.subscribe(token, "/topics/"+LANGUAGE , null);
```